# Outlook VSTO: MailItem does not contain a definition for `HTMLBody`

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I sent an HTML (MIME) message with an HTML table in it to my email account, and now I'm walking through a [sample VSTO program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx).  I've clicked on that particular email message.

I'm here in the code:

```
 using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
 <snip>  

 currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook
        .ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler
        (CurrentExplorer_Event);

 private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
  {
   <snip>
  .
  .
  .
  Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
 if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                            (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
           BREAKPOINT->     itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                            " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
                        mailItem.Display(false);
                    }
```

When I look at `mailItem` in the Immediate Window I get an error:

```
?mailItem.HTMLBody
error CS1061: 'MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'HTMLBody' 
 and no extension method 'HTMLBody' accepting a first argument of 
 type 'MailItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive
 or an     assembly reference?)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the late binding technology (see [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in .Net) for accessing the property.

Do you run the code on a secondary thread? What event handler do you use for accessing the body?

Anyway, the Outlook object model doesn't provide anythyng for signatures. But you can edit the message body at runtime using VBA macros.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to deal with the message body.